# java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host:

Tags: java, exception, connection, rmi

```
  java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: IPSERVER0.0.0.0.0; nested exception     is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
at StartRMI.go(StartRMI.java:14)
at StartRMI.main(StartRMI.java:6)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
... 7 more
```

I get this exception when I try to connect a remote client to my server. My Server is running RMI Server fine, and there no firewall installed. How to fix that issue ?

Comment: Does it really say IPSERVER0.0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 2):

Check all you network adapters ,some time a VM network adapter interferes in this way .
Which is you current `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` is not any more referring to you host name or current machine ,which then create a connection refused problem. My General Recommendation is:

```
1.To check or disable unwanted VM or Network Adapters

2.Ping 127.0.0.1

3.Disable Firewall and Test if all the above doesn't work 

4.Add security Manager with a policy file on you server if you haven't done that.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned which OS you are using, if everything is correct in terms of code and firewall then you may need to check the host entries or ip table rules.

Comment: The OS used is Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Is IPSERVER mapped in /etc/hosts file to the IP address you want?
Check what you get when you do a `hostname -i` or `hostname`.

Try putting your IP address instead of the domain name.

Comment: Yes. The IP is mapped in /etc/hosts.

Comment: Try putting your IP address instead of the domain name.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to localhost or 127.0.0.1?

Comment: It worked! Just add 127.0.0.1 to /etc/hosts with the name from machine.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 should be mapped to "localhost", and your real IP address to your real hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the RMI registry using

```
start rmiregistry
```

for default port or

```
rmiregistry <port_no>
```

for a specified port.